# How do get the network path of local drive

Tags: windows, powershell

How to get the network path of local machine c drive using powershell.

like in my local machine "\Desktop-rgh5sj2\c", which i got by manually

by This pc --> Map Network Drive --> from browse selecting the local c drive.

Comment: You can get your computer name with `$env:COMPUTERNAME` and your system drive with `$env:SystemDrive`

Comment: @  guiwhatsthat   $env:COMPUTERNAME  is giving me as \Desktop-RGH5SJ2\ all are capital letter.  so it is different from the network path name.

Comment: In Windows case doesn't matter for file names and paths.